# Changing the content of the UIScrollView iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am trying to create a scrollable menu bar (which I am succeeding in doing) but now instead I want to add a large button with an image centred in the button, instead of taking up the total width and height of the button

THis is my current code:

```
[scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

[scrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];

scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;

scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;

scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;

UIImage *image;

UIImageView *iv;

UIButton *button;

count = [returned count];

for (int i=0; i<count; i++)

{

image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"coat2.jpg"];

iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,105,120)];

button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,105,120)];

[button setAlpha:100];

[button setTag:1];

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

iv.image = image;

iv.tag=@"coat2.jpg";

iv.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

[iv insertSubview:button atIndex:0];

[button release];

[scrollView addSubview:iv];

[iv release];

}

[scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];

[self layoutScrollImages];

scrollView.delegate = self;
```

the above code creates an image and button over it where the button and image are of the exact same width and height. I want the button to be significantly larger both in height and width.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

2nd attempt (using help from Joseph Tura)

```
[scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    [scrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];

    scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;

    scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;

    scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;

    UIImage *image;

    count = [returned count];

    for (int i=0; i<count; i++)

    {
    image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"coat2.jpg"];
                iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,20,105,120)];

        button = [[ProductButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,20,105,120)];

        [button setAlpha:100];
        [button setTag:1];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        iv.tag=tag;
        iv.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        iv.image = myimage;

        UIView *uiView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,20,105,120)];
        [uiView addSubview:iv];
        button = [[ProductButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,210,240)];
        button.center = CGPointMake(uiView.frame.size.width /2, uiView.frame.size.height/2);
        [button setTag:1];

        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [uiView addSubview:button];

        [scrollView addSubview:uiView];
}
                [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];

    [self layoutScrollImages];

    scrollView.delegate = self;


-----

-(void)layoutScrollImages
{
    //UIImageView *view = nil;
    UIView *view = nil;
    NSArray *subviews = [scrollView subviews];
    CGFloat curXLoc = 0;
    for (view in subviews)
    {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]] && view.tag > 0)
        {
            CGRect frame = view.frame;
            frame.origin = CGPointMake(curXLoc, 0);
            view.frame = frame;

            curXLoc += 110;
        }
    }
    [scrollView setContentSize: CGSizeMake(count*110, [scrollView bounds].size.height)];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not put both elements inside a UIView?

```
UIView *aView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:iv.frame];

[aView addSubview:iv];

button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,210,240)];
button.center = CGPointMake(aView.frame.size.width / 2, aView.frame.size.height / 2);
[aView addSubview:button];
```

Comment: For some strange reason only one image is appearing using the above code

Comment: I used the code you kindly suggested and I get one clickable image in the scrollview and nothing else

Comment: Well that code is only a snippet. Depends on what you have put around it. Care to post the whole thing?

Comment: You are setting button.tag = 1. You are not setting your UIView's tag. You have a condition in your loop that will only position views with a tag > 0...

Comment: Also, you should be centering your imageView (which is bigger) not your button (which is the same size as your UIView). My bad.

Comment: Changed iv.center = CGPointMake(uiView.frame.size.width /2, uiView.frame.size.height/2); and set the uiView tag to 1 so now its displaying all the images, thanks. But the image is still the same size as the UIView and Button

Comment: Sry I had left the image size as the same. IT is appearing smaller. The button is invisible though

Comment: I tried the code and it works as it should... basically. Check this: http://pastebin.com/UzeAQX0U

Comment: You are welcome. :) Please note that I did not pay any attention to memory management there. Lazy me.